# Nested TAILQ double free error

Tags: c

The following code is a minimal example of a problem in a bigger codebase. It can be compiled via a simple `gcc -g main.c`.

I have a list of items, each of which holds a list of attributes. The goal is to parse a list from some input and in order to only ever have completely parsed items in the list, it uses a temporary item that is added to the list once fully parsed.

Since the parsing happens periodically, the list of items must be free'd at some point. The code, as it stands, at this point produces "double free or corruption" in line 49. My question, simply put, is: why does this happen / what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? I can't seem to wrap my head around where memory is corrupted.

#### main.c

```
#include <sys/queue.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct attribute_t {
    char *name;
    TAILQ_ENTRY(attribute_t) attributes;
} attribute_t;

typedef struct item_t {
    char *name;
    TAILQ_HEAD(attributes_head, attribute_t) attributes;

    TAILQ_ENTRY(item_t) items;
} item_t;

TAILQ_HEAD(items_head, item_t) items = TAILQ_HEAD_INITIALIZER(items);
static item_t item_builder;

static void read_item_start(const char *name) {
    TAILQ_INIT(&(item_builder.attributes));
    item_builder.name = strdup(name);
}

static void read_item_end() {
    item_t *new_item = calloc(1, sizeof(item_t));
    memcpy(new_item, &item_builder, sizeof(item_t));
    TAILQ_INSERT_TAIL(&items, new_item, items);

    memset(&item_builder, '\0', sizeof(item_t));
}

static void read_item_attribute(const char *name) {
    attribute_t *new = calloc(1, sizeof(attribute_t));
    new->name = strdup(name);
    TAILQ_INSERT_TAIL(&(item_builder.attributes), new, attributes);
}

static void free_items() {
    item_t *item;
    while (!TAILQ_EMPTY(&items)) {
        item = TAILQ_FIRST(&items);
        free(item->name); // <-- crash

        attribute_t *attribute;
        while (!TAILQ_EMPTY(&(item->attributes))) {
            attribute = TAILQ_FIRST(&(item->attributes));
            free(attribute->name);

            TAILQ_REMOVE(&(item->attributes), attribute, attributes);
            free(attribute);
        }

        TAILQ_REMOVE(&items, item, items);
        free(item);
    }
}

int main() {
    read_item_start("first item");
    read_item_attribute("first attribute");
    read_item_attribute("second attribute");
    read_item_end();

    read_item_start("second item");
    read_item_attribute("first attribute");
    read_item_attribute("second attribute");
    read_item_end();

    free_items();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `TAILQ_INIT` initializes `tqh_last` to be a pointer to `tqh_first`:

```
#define TAILQ_INIT(head)                   \
do {                                       \
    (head)->tqh_first = NULL;              \
    (head)->tqh_last = &(head)->tqh_first; \
} while (0)
```

(`&(head)->tqh_first` is equivalent to the slightly more clear `&((head)->tqh_first)`).

So, when you use `memcpy`, you violate the invariant that `tqh_last` points to the memory location of `tqh_first`.

I think the clean solution would be to initialize a new TAILQ in the copied structure and move all elements from the old list into the new TAILQ.

A slightly less clean but more efficient solution would be to fix the pointer directly.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense (we do the same for status blocks [code that I wrote {a long time ago}]). I'll accept the answer once I actually fixed it and can verify it.

Answer (score 1):

I've inserted printfs after each allocation and free, this is the result:

```
strdup = 0x800e15000
read_item_attribute: calloc = 0x800e20000
read_item_attribute: calloc = 0x800e20020
read_item_end: calloc = 0x800e21000
strdup = 0x800e15020
read_item_attribute: calloc = 0x800e20060
read_item_attribute: calloc = 0x800e20080
read_item_end: calloc = 0x800e21030
free_items(name): 0x800e15000
free_items(attribute->name): 0x800e15010
free_items(attribute): 0x800e20000
free_items(attribute->name): 0x5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a
```

Observe that `free_items(attribute->name): 0x800e15010` is already trying to free something that wasn't allocated. Apparently,

```
attribute = TAILQ_FIRST(&(item->attributes));
```

doesn't give you a struct with an allocated `name` member.

Comment: That explains why it crashes (thanks!), but unfortunately doesn't help me understand what I'm doing wrong / how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: If I `printf` the memory address of `attribute` inside the loop right after assigning it, I can see that it's the same both times. But I can't explain that.